# How to tell Ido to get out of the way when I can already just paste the file name?

Tags: files, ido

I'm trying to make myself use Ido mode. Some times it's nice, but other times it is extremely stupid. Here's my greatest disappointment.

I read some log with full file names, then I copy one name, try open that file.

The way to do this without Ido: <kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>C-y</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

With Ido there are two major problems:

1. If I have the entire file name, there's no way to input that (I must remove the first slash, else even pressing <kbd>//</kbd> will not help.
2. I can't edit intermediate parts of the file name leaving the rest unmodified.

Or can I?

Comment: You can drop back to stock `find-file` with `C-x C-f` and paste in normally. But then, that's more keystrokes. Or you can use Helm if you want a feature rich `find-file` and still satisfy that use case of yours.

Comment: Ah, thanks, nah, I don't do this *so* often that I'd complain about two extra keystrokes. This would actually answer my needs for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Tu Do You should put that down as an answer below. I have found the `C-x C-f` fallback useful so many times!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While an `ido` command is active (`ido-find-file` in this case), you can drop back to the *non-ido* version of the same command (`find-file` in this case) using the ido-default binding `C-x C-f` for `ido-fallback-command`.

To answer you question,

- The first `C-x C-f` will call `ido-find-file`.
- The second `C-x C-f` will fall back to `find-file`.
- Then you can do `C-a C-y C-k` <kbd>RET</kbd> as you usually do to yank a copied file path into the minibuffer.

*Note: In `ido`, `C-x C-f C-x C-f` will do the same thing as `C-x C-f C-f`, i.e. fall back to `find-file`.*

**About `C-f` in `ido`**
In `ido-mode`, `C-f` is bound to `ido-magic-forward-char`. From `ido.el`,

```
(defun ido-magic-forward-char (arg)
  "Move forward in user input or perform magic action.
If no user input is present, or at end of input, perform magic actions:
C-x C-b ... C-f  switch to `ido-find-file'.
C-x C-f ... C-f  fallback to non-Ido `find-file'.
C-x C-d ... C-f  fallback to non-Ido brief `dired'.
C-x d ... C-f    fallback to non-Ido `dired'."
```

Comment: For me it's just `C-f` to get back to `find-file`, not `C-x C-f`.  I don't see that I've customized it (and I, like others here rely on the fallback a lot. `ido` is almost as much trouble as it's worth, after using it for a while now).

Comment: @harpo I just updated the answer above explaining why `C-x C-f C-f` also works.

Comment: Thanks to @kaushalmodi for most of the work. My answer is initially simple like the comment. It should be his answer :) Just a note for credibility.

Comment: This saved my sanity, as ido does not play nicely with tramp when using absolute paths. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Given you're dealing with full path names, other methods may work:

- use `M-x ffap` (`find-file-at-point`): it will automatically read the path name and open the file
- activate `M-x compilation-shell-minor-mode` which will change the font of paths and make them "clickable" (with mouth or `RET`). Clicking on it brings you to that file and the specific line, and you can use `next-error` and `previous-error` to navigate. I often use it, [like in shell-mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Shell#Make_file_paths_clickable).

Answer (score 5):

Since there's always more than one way to do it, here's a variation on @abo-abo's idea that keeps ido completion active rather than falling back to the normal find command.

```
(defun ido-yank ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((path (current-kill 0)))
    (if (file-exists-p path)
        (progn
          (let ((dir (file-name-directory path)))
            (if dir (ido-set-current-directory dir)))
          (setq ido-exit 'refresh)
          (setq ido-text-init (if (file-directory-p path) nil (file-name-nondirectory path)))
          (setq ido-rotate-temp t)
          (exit-minibuffer))
      (yank))))

(define-key ido-file-dir-completion-map (kbd "C-y") 'ido-yank)
```

With this binding:

- If the current kill is a valid directory path, you can start `ido-find-file`, hit `C-y` to jump to the yanked directory, and then continue to use ido completion to choose a file.
- If the current kill is a valid file path, you can start `ido-find-file`, hit `C-y` to jump to the yanked directory and offer the yanked file name as the completion, and hit RET to open that file.
- If the current kill is anything else it gets yanked normally.

Comment: Might it not be better to `let`-bind the various `ido-...` variables rather than `setq` them?  Right now, it looks like you're permanently setting values rather than doing so for the life of the function.

Comment: @Dan I'm following the pattern of ido commands like `ido-next-work-directory`. I think the variables get set so that they survive across the exit-minibuffer call and the subsequent refresh. But I still don't fully grok the ido internals!

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if they get subsequently refreshed anyway.  Just wanted to put in a heads-up.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this:

```
(define-key ido-file-dir-completion-map (kbd "C-y") 'ido-yank)
(defun ido-yank ()
  (interactive)
  (if (file-exists-p (current-kill 0))
      (ido-fallback-command)
    (yank)))
```

If the current kill is a file that exists, doing <kbd>C-y C-y</kbd>
should probably give you what you want.