# Vertico command similar to ido-fallback-command

Tags: completion, vertico

1. In there a vertico command command that causes vertico-find-file
   (not sure of the name, I mean the behavior of file finding during vertico's take over of find-file)
   to drop back to the normal emacs find-file command?
   This question was asked about ido here [ido fallback](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/how-to-tell-ido-to-get-out-of-the-way-when-i-can-already-just-paste-the-file-nam)
2. Is there a vertico command that keep vertigo completion active, but lets the user paste in a path, then vertico begins file name completion using new path?